# XSD check if value is alphabetic order sorted

Tags: xsd

I am stuck on an XSD check, I need to check if a code composed of 4 letters is valid, the first and the second two letters must be in alphabetic order example:

ABCD or CDAB or EFBC etc...

And letters cannot be repeated.

I've got this so far:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NameAddress">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
            <xs:pattern value="(A){0,1}(B){0,1}(C){0,1}(D){0,1}(E){0,1}(F){0,1}(G){0,1}(H){0,1}(J){0,1}(K){0,1}(L){0,1}(M){0,1}(P){0,1}(Q){0,1}(R){0,1}(S){0,1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

But it only checks the alphabetic order in the sequence so if I write ABCD or CDEF it works, but it doesn't look behind and CDAB will fail.

Is there any way to perform this?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Can you use XSD 1.1?  And do you want "AZCB" to be valid because 'Z' is alphabetically after 'A' or invalid because  'Z' is not immediately alphabetically after 'A'?  All of your valid examples show *immediately* alphabetically after only.

Comment: AZCD would be correct because Z is higher than A and the others 2 letters CD are in alphabetical order too, but the code doesn't allow some letters like Z, T etc.. but if it allowed them it would be ok you got what I need but it won't let me do it

Comment: So, when you say *the first and the second two letters must be in alphabetic order* you really mean *all letters must be in alphabetic order*?

Comment: Wait I'll show you an example, ACBE all 4 letters as you can see are not in alphabetic order, but the first two and second two are: (AC) and (BE) 'cause C comes after A and E comes after B, only the first two letters and the last 2 need to be in alphabetic order, sure ABCD would work too since the first to (AB) and second (CD), with the code I used above instead it checks for all 4 letters to be in alphabetic order so ABCD works but ACBE doesn't